# Add hyperlink to a web page in adaptive card 1.0 to be displayed on MS Teams

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have added an adaptive card displaying list of meetings scheduled with the link to the meeting. I want the link in the list to be clickable. With Action.OpenUrl we can only get a button launches the given URL in an external web browser. But in my case, I have list of meetings with the link that needs to be clickable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptive Cards use a form of "Markdown" syntax (similar to here on stack overflow) and they include the ability to have a url, just with the markdown syntax. You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format) for more, including things like **bold** and *italics*. Basically, you encode your link like this [name for the link] (http://the.url.com), but notice I had a space between "]" and "(", which is just to show the text nicely here in the answer, otherwise stack overflow would show my sample as a link! It should actually be: link](http. See the link I sent for more though, if it's still not clear.